# Child element z-index inside element with transform property

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transforms

I'm having a problem and I'd like to know if you guys can help me out with it.

As shown in the snippet, I have some elements with

```
transform: translate(0,0);
```

And then, inside them, I have a "dropdown" element that is shown when you click a button.

The problem comes when part of this dropdown gets hidden behind other elements, and I found out that this is happening because its parent element has this transform property.

[image]

My code has more stuff, the snippet is just an example. I can't get rid of the transform property.

I'd like to know if there is any solution for this. I'm trying to solve it using just CSS.

Cheers!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.template-options-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.template-options-dropdown.open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there *maybe* no CSS-only solution - CSS3 transitions creates a *new stacking context* - see the relevant doc description and [`this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154992/how-to-scale-so-that-container-also-grows-and-takes-up-space/46220651#46220651) for another effect:

> If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context
>   will be created.
>
> Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=a#transform)

You can easily replace `translate(0,0)` there with `position: relative` and add a `z-index` more than zero to `.template-options-dropdown` ***to solve the problem***.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.template-options-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  /*transform: translate(0, 0);*/
  position: relative; /*ADDED*/
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;/*ADDED*/
}

.template-options-dropdown.open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

A ***hacky* solution** that messes up the *wrapping* - you can add more transforms:

1. Add `scaleY(-1)` for the `ul` to make the list backwards because of the fact that the a list item with higher index comes over the one with a lower index.
2. Add an inversion `scaleY(-1)` to the `li` to bring the world back to normal.
3. Also *clear* the `li` floats.

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.template-options-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
  transform: scaleY(-1);/*ADDED*/
}
.boxes:after {/*ADDED*/
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, 0) scaleY(-1);/*ADDED*/
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.template-options-dropdown.open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

If `translate(0,0)` still can't be removed, you have no option other than use javascript:

1. Invert the list stacking by giving a `z-index` equal to the index in the list.
2. Add `position:relative` to the `li`

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ADDED
  $($('ul.boxes > li').get().reverse()).each(function(index){
     $(this).css('z-index', index);
  });

  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.template-options-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  position: relative;/*ADDED*/
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.template-options-dropdown.open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative. So apply `position: relative` to the `li` element.

For fixed number of elements, you can try

```
.boxes li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 8;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 7;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 6;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(7) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(8) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Or for unknown number of elements, you can apply it dynamically with the script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.template-options-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  position: relative;
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.template-options-dropdown.open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 8;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 7;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 6;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(7) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.boxes li:nth-child(8) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anurag. The thing is that those li could be more or less, so... that solution is not good in that case.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, for unknown number of elements, you can apply the styles using dynamically with the script.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was trying to find a solution with just CSS :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but if it was me I would set the `.open` class on either the `<li>` or the `div.download-container`, set a massive z-index using that, and use the cascade to open the sub-menu. We also have to set `position:relative;` on the element that we're setting z-index on, otherwise z-index does nothing.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parents('li').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes >li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  position:relative;
}

.boxes >li.open {
    z-index:500;
}

.download-container {
  background: rgba(40, 39, 39, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.download-container .dropdown-container button {
  background: #0bb9ab;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.template-options-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.boxes li.open .template-options-dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
}

.template-options-dropdown li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  <li><div class="download-container">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" name="button">Download</button>

        <ul class="template-options-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Original</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Thumb</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Web</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Large web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```