# Position of the div that follows a scaled div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<section class="mysection">
  <div class="parallax"></div>
</section>

 <section class="some-text">
  blah.....
</section>
```

Before using parallax on the `parallax` div, `some text` just sits immediately below the bottom border of `mysection`. This is the CSS for `parallax`.

```
.parallax{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

When I scale `parallax` by 1.11111111, the `parallax` uses 100% width of the viewport. However, `some text` does not sits right beneath the `parallax` anymore. Instead, it overlaps with the `parallax` area. Here is a picture of a real-life situation:

[image]

How can I make `some text` always sits beneath the bottom border of `mysection` without overlap?

To be more detailed, I use a tool called ScrollMagic for this work if this is relevant.

Comment: the *overlapping* is expected, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154992/how-to-scale-so-that-container-also-grows-and-takes-up-space)... you can remove the *scaling*?

Comment: kukkuz, thanks for chiming in! I have to have the scaling because it is part of the web design.

Comment: maybe a *hacky* fix using some `padding` or `overflow: hidden`... You can't avoid the overlapping I guess

Comment: Thanks for follow up with me. `padding` could be the solution for text. In my case, it is more than jus text. I have another question about an absoute-positioned image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556948/make-parallaxed-element-completely-opaque

Comment: If the next div is always supposed to come after the parallax one, why not put both in a container and scale that one.

Comment: The text is not part of the parallex/tween by design.