# Make parallaxed element completely opaque

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<section class="mysection">
  <div class="parallax">
    <div>
       <svg></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="back">
    <div class="triangle">
        <img src="img/red-triangle-bkgrd.png">
    </div>      
</section>
```

This is the CSS in LESS:

```
    .parallax{
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

  section.back {
    .triangle {
        position: relative;
        img {
            position: absolute;
            right:0;
            top: 0;     
        }
    }
  }
```

Before using parallax on the `parallax`, `back` just sits immediately below the bottom border of `mysection`.

When I scale `parallax` by 1.11111111, the `parallax` uses 100% width of the viewport. However, `back` does not sits right beneath the `parallax` anymore. Instead, it overlaps with the `parallax` area. Here is a picture of a real-life situation:

[image]

How can I make `back` in the overlap area invisible? Put it another way, how can I make svg or its containers completely opaque without showing the overlaped image beneath it?

I tried 'opacity:1` on svg and its containers, but it is not working.

To be more detailed, I use a tool called ScrollMagic for this work if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the stacking order using `z-index`.  Try setting the following:

```
.mysection {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This should ensure that whatever's in your `.mysection` (such as the svg/map) passes *over* whatever intersects (assuming you don't apply a greater z-index to the other elements).

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. So easy. I tried z-index on other containing divs but not on this one. Best.

Comment: No worries.  Might have been that you hadn't set `position` on the element you were trying to apply `z-index` to.